# Script works with ./file_name, but I get error when I start it using sh file_name

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Script works with `./file_name`, but I get error when I start it using `sh file_name`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Scenarijus, kuris is teksto failo paima pirmoje eiluteje esancius zodzius ir sukuria naujus katalogus tokiais paciais pavadinimais, jusu pasirinktame kataloge"
echo "  "
echo "Iveskite teksto faila is kurio norite paimti pirma eilute"
read failas
echo "Nurodykite kataloga kuriame noresite sukurti naujus katalogus"
read direktorija
mkdir -p $direktorija
read -a pavadinimai < "$failas"
for pavadinimas in "${pavadinimai[@]}"; do
    mkdir "$direktorija/$pavadinimas"
done
```

When I start script using sh I get error:
`file_name: 9: Illegal option -a filename: 10: filename: Bad substitution`

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the the script directly, the hashbang line will be parsed for an interpreter. As you use `#!/bin/bash` the bash shell will used to execute your script, so the executed command is `/bin/bash ./file_name`.

Bash offers a superset of commands to the sh, so you can run sh scripts in the bash but not vice versa. In your case for example, the `read` command of sh does not know the `-a` parameter that bash knows.

Call your script with `bash file_name` and everything should be fine.